# Subsetting a table in R

Tags: r, subset

In R, I've created a 3-dimensional table from a dataset. The three variables are all factors and are labelled H, O, and S. This is the code I used to simply create the table:

```
attach(df)
test <- table(H, O, S)
```

Outputting the flattened table produces this table below. The two values of S were split up, so these are labelled S1 and S2:

```
ftable(test)

+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
|     H     |     O     | S1  | S2  |
+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
| Isolation | Dead      |   2 |  15 |
|           | Sick      |  64 |  20 |
|           | Recovered | 153 | 379 |
| ICU       | Dead      |   0 |  15 |
|           | Sick      |   0 |   2 |
|           | Recovered |   1 |   9 |
| Other     | Dead      |   7 | 133 |
|           | Sick      |   4 |  20 |
|           | Recovered |  17 | 261 |
+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

The goal is to use this table object, subset it, and produce a second table. Essentially, I want only "Isolation" and "ICU" from H, "Sick" and "Recovered" from O, and only S1, so it basically becomes the 2-dimensional table below:

```
+-----------+------+-----------+
|           | Sick | Recovered |
+-----------+------+-----------+
| Isolation |   64 |       153 |
| ICU       |    0 |         1 |
+-----------+------+-----------+
S = S1
```

I know I could first subset the dataframe and then create the new table, but the goal is to **subset the table object itself**. I'm not sure how to retrieve certain values from each dimension and produce the reduced table.

**Edit: ANSWER**

I now found a much simpler method. All I needed to do was reference the specific columns in their respective directions. So a much simpler solution is below:

```
> test[1:2,2:3,1]
                O
H                Sick Healed
  Isolation      64    153
  ICU            0     1
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I edited the question and added the first 20 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset the data before running `table`, example:

```
ftable(table(mtcars[, c("cyl", "gear", "vs")]))
# vs  0  1
# cyl gear         
# 4   3        0  1
#     4        0  8
#     5        1  1
# 6   3        0  2
#     4        2  2
#     5        1  0
# 8   3       12  0
#     4        0  0
#     5        2  0

# subset then run table
ftable(table(mtcars[ mtcars$gear == 4, c("cyl", "gear", "vs")]))       
#          vs 0 1
# cyl gear       
# 4   4       0 8
# 6   4       2 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working quite right. When I'm subsetting and entering the values I want to keep, the table produced doesn't remove the unwanted values. It keeps them and fills in 0s for their values in the table rather than removing them altogether. I want the table to be 2x2, but it's still 3x3.

Comment: Sorry, I was encountering this issue because of user error. I refreshed my R session and it seems to be working as intended now. Thank you!